# How do I test my loading screen when my page loads to fast?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the way my loading screen works, is when the page loads, the loading screen disappears. However this is hard to test and make it works as my page loads in under a second and I see the glimpse of my loading screen. Is there anyway to perhaps slow down the speed in some way?

Comment: In whatever code (you chose not to share with us) that unloads the loading screen, place a timeout that is long enough for you to test. If using automated testing (Selenium), have the test tool take a screenshot.

Comment: Randy is right in principle. If you want more specific answers then you're going to have to provide code samples so we know what the loading steps are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome DevTool, there's a functionality called throttling in Network tab, it can simulate bad network condition, you may want to try that. 
[image]